# Interface Builder - custom class not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am an iOS developer using mac OS X 10.8.5 and Xcode 5. I am attempting to make my iPhone app universal, but my viewController's objects (ex. buttons, text views, etc. ) won't connect to the viewController's class. I tried adding a custom class to the viewController, but the custom class automatically goes back to UIViewController (yes, i checked the spelling of the class). The custom class works on my iPhone storyboard but not with my iPad storyboard. I also tried restarting Xcode and even my iMac, which hasn't worked so far.

Here is my class' code (.h file):

```
@interface hackScreen : UIView
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtfieldOne;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtfieldTwo;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtfieldThree;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtfieldFour;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtfieldFive;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtfieldSix;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtfieldSeven;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *DatRandomBinary;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *leDoneMessage;



- (IBAction)tallStar:(id)sender;
- (void) oneStar;
- (void) tigerStar;
- (void) blackStar;
- (void) pineStar;
- (void) blueStar;
- (void) redStar;
- (void) cloudStar;
- (void) assemblyCode;
- (void) assemblyTwo;
- (void) radioActive;

@end
```

And here is the picture of my viewController's identity inspector:
[image: viewController identity inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Your `hackscreen` class is a subclass of `UIView` not of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Drop UIView to xib,set her class to your class, then go to viewController outlets and make relations between "view" field of viewController and dropped view.

Answer (score 0):

please change:

```
     @interface hackScreen : UIView
```

to

```
     @interface hackScreen : UIViewController
```

Answer (score -1):

Your hackScreen class needs to be a subclass of UIViewController in order for it to show up in the inspector. So you simply need to change the hackScreen class to be a subclass of UIViewController, not UIView.

E.g.

@interface hackScreen : UIViewController

...

@end